# For loop inside SQL Create Table query

Tags: java, sql, create-table, vertica

I am trying to Create a table Model (i, y1, y2 .... yd) in Vertica using JAVA. Column i is integer and all others are REAL. I used the following code to create it. However it is showing syntax error at or near null. Does anybody know what that means? The connection works for the program.

```
 public void createMODEL(int d)
     {
         int x;
         try
     {

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String createquery = "CREATE TABLE MODEL ( "
                            + "i integer primary key ";
        for (x=1;x<=d;x++) createquery+=  " , " + Y[x] + " REAL ";
        createquery += ")";
        stmt.executeUpdate(createquery);   
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println("Error while executing create model query");
        System.out.print(e);
        System.exit(0);

     }

 }
```

Y is defined as follows -

```
String Y[]=new String[100];
```

Comment: Can you share the SQL this method produces and the exact error you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Error while executing create model query
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "null"BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: At least one of your `Y[x]` is `null`.

Comment: You show how you initialized the array `Y` to 100 `null`s.  Did you ever put any `String` values in it after that?  Your loop looks at `Y[1], Y[2], ..., Y[d]`; did you instead put your strings at `Y[0], Y[1],...,Y[d-1]`?

Comment: Yes, @KevinAnderson, i think you are right. How can i initialize the values of the string array?

Comment: If the names of the REAL fields are literally "Y1", "Y2", etc., you don't even need the array.  Just use `createQuery += ", Y" + i  + " REAL"` in your loop.

Comment: i didn't think about that. it actually works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should check if `Y[x]` is not null:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String createquery = "CREATE TABLE MODEL ( "
                            + "i integer primary key ";
for (x=1;x<=d;x++)  {
    if (Y[x] != null)  createquery+=  " , " + Y[x] + " REAL ";
}
createquery += ")";
stmt.executeUpdate(createquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for MySQL. Try this.

```
String Y[] = new String[100];
Y[0] = "h";
Y[1] = "ha";
Y[2] = "hat";
Y[3] = "hati";
Y[4] = "hatim";

System.out.println("Your columns array : " + Arrays.deepToString(Y));

String createquery = "CREATE TABLE MODEL ( " + "i integer primary key ";

for (int i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
    if (Y[i] != null)
        createquery += " , " + Y[i] + " REAL ";
}
createquery += ");";

System.out.println("Your create query : " + createquery);
```